# Java - Get Url Mapping from inside Filter#doFilter() method Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlet-filters

From inside the filter's `doFilter()` method, is it possible to get the Servlet class name to which a URL would be mapped if it had not been intercepted by a Filter? I am looking to fetch a datastore whose key is the logging property `RequestLogs.getUrlMapEntry()` within `doFilter`, but am not sure how to retrieve that information.